# Why $\|u\|_{L^r}\leq C\|\nabla u\|_{L^p}^{a}\|u\|_{L^q}^{1-a}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $u\in \mathcal C_c^1(\mathbb R^n)$ and $p>n$. Let $r>0$ s.t. $$\frac{1}{r}=a\left(\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{n}\right)+\frac{1-a}{q},$$
with $a\in [0,1]$, $p>1$ and $q\geq 1$. I'm trying to understand why $$\|u\|_{L^r(\mathbb R^n)}\leq C\|u\|_{W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^n)}^a\|u\|_{L^q(\mathbb R^n)}^{1-a},$$
with $C$ independent of $u$.

- I thought first using the fact that $W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^n) \subset L^\infty (\mathbb R^n)$, but it's not conclusive.
- But I know using Morrey's theorem that there is $C$ independent of $u$ s.t. $$\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{|x-y|^{1-\frac{n}{p}}}\leq C\|\nabla u\|_{L^p(\mathbb R^n)},$$
  but even with this information, I can't conclude.
- By a scaling argument, I can consider $\|u\|_{L^q}=\|u\|_{W^{1,p}}=1$, and thus, I have to prove that $u$ is uniformly bounded for the $r$ norm. I know that the injection $W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^n)\subset L^\infty (\mathbb R^n)$ is continuous and thus there is $C$ independent of $u$ s.t. $$\|u\|_{L^\infty }\leq C.$$
  Now, I know that on a compact $K$, $L^{\infty }(K)$ is continuously injected in $L^{r}(K)$. So if I denote $K$ the support of $u$, I indeed have $\|u\|_{L^r(\mathbb R^n)}=\|u\|_{L^r}(K)\leq C$, and thus I can conclude, but since $K$ depend on $u$, the constant will depend on $u$, and thus, it doesn't solve my problem.

Any help is welcome :-)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gagliardo%E2%80%93Nirenberg_interpolation_inequality

Comment: It is called Gagliardo–Nirenberg interpolation inequality. For the proof of this, please refer to http://www.numdam.org/article/ASNSP_1959_3_13_2_115_0.pdf

Comment: @Icesea: Yes I know this article, and they indeed says that it's a consequence of Morrey's theorem (more or less... they used the cone property, but it's the same)... But as I said (second bullet), I can't conclude with this information. May-be you can give me a hint from this ? :-)

Comment: Please check my proof. It is not difficult, if you know some result first.

Comment: @Jack : any book that talk about sobolev space. See for example the evans page 280 (morrey's inequality), or the brezis (analyse fonctionelle) page 166

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please see the proof below, which is from Adams' book "Sobolev space".  Also, in the Theorem 5.9 in Adams' book, the restriction $p\leq q$ is removed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Log convexity of $L^p$ norm suggest $p,q>0$, and the sobolev embedding $W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^n)\subset L^{p^*}(\mathbb R^n)$ suggest $p<n$. But as I wrote in my question, I need the case where $p>n$, and your proof doesn't work for this case since $p^*\leq 0$.

Comment: @MSE Please see the update. For the details, you can refer to the book

Comment: thanks a lot, I'll see tomorrow (and upvote and accept if I'm satisfy :-))

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers. [Scanned pages from books are discouraged on SE network](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/155600/259305). Questions should contain sufficient context so that it is [answerable with the text alone](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807/290189).

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_\Omega |u|^r=\int_\Omega |u|^{r-q}|u|^q\leq \|u^{r-q}\|_{L^\infty }\|u\|_{L^q}^q\leq C,$$
et voilà !